# Photo edits in iOS 7 do not save when exported to PC

Tags: ios, photos, dropbox

I applied some edits to my photo using iOS 7's default photo editor: red eye correction, auto enhance, etc.

It looks great when I preview the image on iPhone, but when I look at the image on my PC it looks the same as the original: all the edits are gone. I use the Dropbox app on iOS to sync my camera roll to my PC through the cloud.

What do I need to do to push the edited photo to my PC?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem ! and for now, i haven't find any solution. Of course you can send to yourself the edited picture by email or by facebook but it's really not the same quality

Comment: Can we assume you connect the iOS device over USB and see the files as USB connected drives? (Or is there a different "export" that is happening?

Comment: @bmike i upload to my PC via dropbox app.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Directly copying from the iPhone doesn't help either. All the auto enhance, and other such edits disappear when they are copied to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try emailing the photos to yourself.

When you edit photos, iOS doesn't actually modify the JPG file. Instead, it saves an XML file with the same name that contains information about what edits were made—that's why edits "disappear" when you copy the JPG. They were never there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Photos shared from the Dropbox app have their filters and corrections fully applied (at least as of iOS 7.1.1 and Dropbox 3.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

I know a solution. But it is too pain.

Open the edited pic in PicsArt and then just save it without doing anything. 
And the pic will be there in PicsArt album which will be the final product from inbuilt editor.

But doing this for bulky files seperately is really pain.

Actually I was ended up in this page while searching a solution for this same problem.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any other solution in the web.

Answer (score 0):

Flickr uploads seem to retain the edits... looks to me like the current Dropbox *doesn't*.